# JBPM Persistence issue

Tags: persistence, upgrade, jbpm

After upgrading JBPM to 7.13 from 7.11 the data persisted at human task is creating 2 records in the table instead of one. Anyone faced this issue or know why this could happen?

Upgrade JBPM created work tasks, when work tasks are created expected it to create a single record for the Java object that was set for persistence. However 2 records are created in the table for the object.